# OAuth Protected API Accessible From Local Javascript Application

Tags: ruby, api, backbone.js

I apologize if this has been asked, and answered before, but I have hunted all throughout the site, tried about 2 dozen search combinations, Google, etc and still not hit an answer on this.

I am building a single page (Well, login/sign up pages will be static but otherwise) javascript application. I decided I wanted to take Twitter's approach and build an API for it, and consume that with the javascript application.

I am using Rails, and plan to use something along the lines of Versionist for the API, Authlogic, or custom, authentication system, and Doorkeeper for oauth.

So, how do I consume the API locally (Via the javascript application) but still protect it behind OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the js OAuth2 library I'm using: https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso

It's been working very well for me.

Give info about your app:

```
jso_configure({
    "your_app": {
        client_id: "client id of the application your registered in your provider",
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080",
        authorization: "https://www.your_app.com/oauth/authorize"
    }
});
```

Then, when you need to, or when your app launches, authorize the user:

```
jso_ensureTokens({
    "your_app": ["public", "write"]
});
```

And that's it, you'll now be able to send requests to your provider api:

```
$.oajax({
    url: "https://api.your_app.com/v1/lala/rsvp",
    jso_provider: "your_app",
    jso_scopes: ["public", "write"],
    jso_allowia: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Response (your_app):");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

ps: I wouldn't use Authlogic, it's super old.

Comment: So, I would need two servers, one for the API, one for the pretty much static frontend, and then I would have to setup an application for the front-end app in the OAuth provider, correct?